# bring the last loaded controls back when i restart the machine

Tags: c#-2.0

I am working in video application in my application am using many controls for user friendly first i will Load the base from only after that i ll load the other controls based on user need.... here my need is if user load ten controls in this case if he shutdown the machine means when he restart the machine i need to bring the all controls back what he was load the controls before he shutdown. thanks in advance

is there is any possible to achive this without store the current control set, and positions etc..

Comment: "load the other controls based on user need", where do you get the 'need' from? If it's via user's actions, then you will need to persist these information or preferences to file or a DB/registry everytime a related action takes place. Upon loading the app, read from this file/DB to reload the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making extension methods to Control class? 
(Actually, appropriate .NET abstract base class, a sub-class of Control class, depending on UI. Do you use Windows Forms or XAML or ASP.NET?)

Something like:

```
public static class MyPositionExtensions{
    public static void SaveState(this Control c){ /* Save position to xml-file */ }
    public static void RestoreState(this Control c){ /* Load from xml-file */ }
}
```

Then in your closing just loop like

```
foreach(var c in MyControls)c.SaveState();
```

and opening like

```
foreach(var c in MyControls)c.RestoreState();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at something like

- [Form and Control Position and Size
  Utility](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/formcontrolpositionsize.aspx)
- [Save and restore Form position and
  layout with this component](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/RealPosition.aspx)

Basically what it boils down to, is that you need a way to store the current control set, and positions (possibly values too) to some sort of storage (XML file, Registry, Database) when the user exits your form/application.

Then once they reopen the form/application, you need to retrieve these settings for the given user (if any is available) and restore the form/application to that state.